# How can I check if a row is empty in mySQL using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is how I would normally check for empty results: `mysql_fetch_assoc`

However, I am using PDO for a client and in this login function, I want to return some text or a number or boolean to say a row was found or not.

```
public function Login ($email,$password)
{
  $sqlQuery="SELECT * FROM db_user WHERE email= '".$email."'  AND password='".$password." '";
  $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery); // prepare a PDO statement
  $statement -> execute();

  $dataSet= [];
  if(mysql_num_rows($statement) == 1){
    echo 'login true';
  } else {
    echo 'login false';
  }
```

Comment: so this works? or not ?

Comment: use`$count = $statement->num_rows;` instead `mysql_num_rows`

Comment: Try using a `COUNT(*)` statement instead. You can't use both `PDO` and `mysql` at the same time. Well you could but it would be silly...and also not in the way you are trying.

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` isn't PDO. You can't mix APIs like that. It should be `$statement->numRows()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both other answers are essentially unacceptable.
And not because they lack cleanness but because they are awfully dangerous

```
public function Login ($email,$password)
{
  $sql="SELECT 1 FROM db_user WHERE email=?  AND password=?";
  $stmt = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sql);
  $statement -> execute([$email, $password]);
  return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
```

You should be using prepared statements, not just mimicking them.

Comment: on line '$statement -> execute($email, $password);' the 'execute' method expecting an array rather than string. 
It'll should be like '$statement -> execute(array($email, $password));'

Comment: Not seen @Your Common Sense in a long time... though you were banned

Answer (score 0):

```
  $sqlQuery="SELECT * FROM db_user WHERE email= '".$email."'  AND password='".$password." '";
  $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery); // prepare a PDO statement
  $statement -> execute();
  $rows = $statement ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if( ! $rows)
  {
    die('Empty Records');
  }
```

Comment: This looks really clean.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $sqlQuery= "SELECT * FROM db_user WHERE email= ? AND password= ?";
  $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery); // prepare a PDO

  // pass parameter to tackle [SQL Injection][1]
  $stmt->execute(array($email, $password)); 

  $result = $stmt->fetch();
  if( $result ) {
      echo "login true";
  }else{
      echo "login false";
  }
```

Comment: [**Do not** use try catch for error reporting](http://phpdelusions.net/try-catch)

Comment: @YourCommonSense I never know that. Editing my answer.